# How to add security in odoo for adding,editing,deleting and viewing of data?

Tags: security, odoo-8

I am currently developing a room booking module in odoo 8. Many users can  book rooms. Every users can view the details of booking done by other people. But a User can't edit or delete the details created by another user. But he can create, delete and EDIT his own booking. How this can be applied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Book.room:

```
user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', 'User')

@api.model
def create(self, values)

    values['user_id'] = self.env.context.uid

    return super(YourClassName, self).create(values)

@api.multi
def write(self, values)

    if self.user_id.id != self.env.context.uid:
        raise Warning('You cant edit this document')

return super(YourClassName, self).write(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

- Add a folder in your model called security
- Add a file called ir.model.access.csv
- Add a group, or select a group that you will use (from Configuration > users > groups). We will take the accounting one from Account module, but you can create your own.
- Add a header like this:

"id","name","model_id:id","group_id:id","perm_read","perm_write","perm_create","perm_unlink"

Lets say that your model is book.room, account group has two rights, "manager" and "user":

the manager line would be like that (he can read, edit, create and delete):

```
"access_book_room_manager","book.room manager access", "model_book_room", "account.group_account_manager",1,1,1,1
```

the user line (only read):

```
"access_book_room_user","book.room user access", "model_book_room", "account.group_account_manager",1,0,0,0
```

Now, when you create an user and give the group access, depending if you select user or manager, he would have access to only read or everything.

Comment: If i add like this means user can only VIEW. Actually manager and user can book rooms. i.e create, edit,delete options.  But one user should not make any alteration on others details (booking details). How it can be done?

Comment: Can you giveme use cases? step A) user 1 creates a room B) user 2 want to edit it but he cant, C) user 1 wants to edit it but he can because he created it? something like that

Comment: Exactly. User 1 book a room, then he can edit,delete it. User 2 can not edit the booking of user 1, but should be able to see that. Also User 2 can create a new booking.

Comment: Maybe the access rights are not the answer then. I would put an user_id field, when you create this record save this in the book.room object. Then, you can overwrite the function "Write" with a constrain that if the user id that is editing isnt the same that created it raise an error "You can not edit this document". Need me to code it or you understand?

Comment: I am afraid that i didn't understood. Can you please give me an example code or something?